# Web3 js installation error

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, npm

I want to install webjs so I run the below command but it is showing an error.

> $ sudo npm install -g web3

```
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/web3-js/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nithin/.npm/_logs/2019-09-18T09_41_14_857Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try this: open the `packge-lock.json` file which was created where you've just executed that `npm install` command, search for `WebSocket` in it, and change `http://github.com` to `git://github.com`

Comment: there is no WebSocket inside packge-lock.json file

Comment: Which OS are you using? From the error message it seems you lack the git command.

Comment: I am using ubuntu OS

Answer (score 2):

I am expecting that you already executed `npm init` at first.

I assume you are using windows? I always develop blockchain related stuff on Ubuntu.

Here is what you need to do on windows to set it up properly.

**Step 1:** `npm install -g --production windows-build-tools`

**Step 2:** `npm install -g node-gyp`

Now it should work!

If you still have a problem make sure that your `git` is installed globally and accessible.

Comment: The log shows slashes `/` as path separator so it can't be native Windows, so it is Linux or Macos and there installing windows-build-tools doesn't work.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for pointing that out. I have already mentioned the other solution to this problem. For the sake of completeness I will leave the other info for windows users.

Comment: @NiklasFeurstein, I am using using ubuntu OS